# changes are not getting updated ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS.   I am trying to include profile.html within profiletest.html by using ng-include.

Given below is the code of my profiletest.html

**profiletest.html**

```
  <body>
    <div ng-app="guestProfileApp">
      <div ng-controller="guestProfileController">
            <button ng-click="getProfile(401)">Show Profile</button>  
            <ng-include ng-if="showProfile" src="'profile.html'"></ng-include>
       </div>
  </div>
```

When I am making changes to the profile.html code,  the changes are not getting updated in when I refreshed the profiletest.html in browser.

Comment: did you try hard refresh ?

Comment: I did hard refresh but still not getting refreshed. In chrome I tried to open in new incognito window it was refreshed only once, but if I made changes again but not getting updated even in incognito window

Comment: Can you share your code online?

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate the browser cache - In Chrome Dev Tools on the bottom right click on the gear and tick the option.

Disable cache (while DevTools is open)

In Firefox there is the same option in Debugger -> Settings -> Advanced Section
(Not sure if it works in firefox. Alot of people say it doesn't work for them)